# Batch: How to read a path from a double-clicked file?

Tags: batch-file, path, double-click

I am thinking about associating a file type extension to a batch script (.foo), so when double-clicking a file with .foo extension, this script will execute. The point is I do not know if there is a way to tell the script the path of the "executed" file (ie, which variable, if any, holds the path of the double clicked file).

Thank you.

Comment: `~dp0` contains the path of the batch file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The executed file is passed as first argument to the script.
A simple example will show.
Create a batchfile (for example foo_command.cmd) which contains:

```
echo %* > %~dpn0.log
```

Execute your desired filetype and connect it to the batchfile.
This will write a file named foo_command.log (in the directory of foo_command.cmd) which contains all arguments passed to the script. You will see, it is the full path of the executed File.

In general the variable **%1** in the script holds the path and there are no other variables set by default.